How can I evaluate the bounds of this integral?
I have got this integral from a fourier transform:
$$\int_{-\infty}^0 e^{-ikx+x/4}+\int_0^{\infty} e^{-ikx-x/4}dx$$ Apparently the integrals give:
$$=\frac{1}{1/4 -ik}+\frac{1}{1/4 +ik}$$
But how? I'm trying to evaluate the bounds at infinity:
$$\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{e^{x(-ik-1/4)}}{-ik-1/4}=\infty?$$ but I get infinity when it should converge? I really don't know how to evaluate the bounds.

@AnneBauval oops, my bad, editing.

What's the limit of $e^{-x/4}\cos kx$ when $x\to\infty$?

@JyrkiLahtonen should be zero, no?

Correct. So why did you get $\infty$ on the second line from the bottom?

@JyrkiLahtonen but why should I evaluate the real part of the $e^{-ikx}$ to get the solution?

Do the same for the imaginary part.

@JyrkiLahtonen if I get 0, what is the solution for the whole limit? 0 as well? Is this a theorem I can look more into? Because this is the first time I see this

A general result is that if $x\to\infty$ along the real axis (so not a complex variable) and $\alpha$ is complex number with a negative real part, then
$$e^{\alpha x}\to 0.$$ You basically verified this yourself using
$$e^{(a+bi)x}=e^{ax}\left(\cos bx+i\sin bx\right).$$ Alternatively
$$|e^{(a+bi)x}|=e^{ax},$$ and when this tends to zero, so will the complex limit.
